# Two SQL Server queries with different where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to merge two very similar queries. The only different thing is in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
    COUNT(*) as WinnerCount
FROM
    table t1
WHERE
    t1.Result = 'Winner'
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)
```

and the second with *Loser* clause:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
    COUNT(*) as LoserCount
FROM
    table t1
WHERE
    t1.Result = 'Loser'
GROUP BY
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a result set like this:

```
Date       |    WinnerCount    | LoserCount
01/01/2017       24                  16
17/02/2017       13                  9
```

I've tried to merge this with join as two resultset:

```
SELECT
    FirstSet.Date
FROM 
    (SELECT
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
         COUNT(*) as Count
     FROM
         table t1
     WHERE
         t1.Result = 'Winner'
     GROUP BY
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)) AS FirstSet
JOIN
    (SELECT
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
         COUNT(*) as Count
     FROM
         table t1
     WHERE
         t1.Result = 'Loser'
     GROUP BY
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)) AS SecondSet ON FirstSet.Date = SecondSet.Date
ORDER BY 
    FirstSet.Date
```

but in results I got only dates :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this query. Insted of counting all the rows, you may SUM all the occurrences of the required text (*Winner" or "Loser" in this case).

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Winner' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WinnerCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Loser' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LoserCount
from table t1
where t1.Result in ( 'Winner', 'Loser')
group by
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)
```

Answer (score 3):

The above accepted answer will provide you with the correct result however if you wanted to keep the Count and not use Sum to aggregate the results then you could alternatively use the below:

```
select
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Winner' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as WinnerCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Loser' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as LoserCount
from table as t1
where t1.Result in ('Winner', 'Loser')
group by 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) as Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Winner' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS WinnerCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'Loser' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS LoserCount
FROM
     table t1
group by
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101)
```